# Display complete value instead of 1E6

Tags: php, format

I'm currently working on code which deals with variables which have a lot of digits after the comma.

At this moment, I have a variable which contains 830 / 1E8; The result of this variable gives me 8.3E-6, How can I make PHP return that result in a format like this; 0.00000830 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use number_format method and specify the number of decimal places

```
echo number_format(8.3E-6, 8); // => 0.00000830
```